# Qt creator - Plugin loader error message

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, dependencies

When I open Qtcreator I get the following error message (from a notification box): "The following plugins have errors and cannot be loaded" with the list of the plugins containing errors: CMakeProjectManager, Qnx, RemoteLinux and Valgrind.
When I click over the name of a plugin I obtain some details like that

```
Could not resolve dependency 'AnalyzerBase(3.1.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'Core(3.1.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'ProjectExplorer(3.1.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'TextEditor(3.1.1)'
```

I use Linux (ubuntu 14.04) and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You have an incomplete or corrupt installation of Qt Creator, most likely. Try reinstalling it.